# If $A^{2011}=0$ then $A^2=0$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Let the matrix $A=(a_{ij})=Mat(2, R)$, satisfies $A^{2011}=0$

Prove that:  $A^2=0$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does $\text{Mat}(2, R)$ mean?

Comment: This is matrix 2-row squares

Answer (score 14):

Consider the minimal polynomial $p(x)$ of $A$. By hypothesis, $p(x) \mid x^{2011}$, whence $p(x) = x^k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Also $deg(p(x)) \leq 2$, and so $p(x) = x$ or $p(x) = x^2$.

In either case, $A^2 = 0$.

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of this exercise, of course, is to illustrate that if $A$ is an $n\times n$ nilpotent matrix, then $A^n=0$. However, since $n=2$ here, we have a more elementary proof.

As $A^{2011}=0$, $A$ is singular. So, its two rows are linearly dependent and hence $A=uv^\top$ for some vectors $u$ and $v$. It follows that for $m\ge2$, $A^m=(uv^\top)^m=uv^\top uv^\top\cdots uv^\top=(v^\top u)^{m-1}A$. So, ...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try to reason on possible characteristic polynomial of A.

Answer (score 1):

$A^n=O_2=> det(A^n)=0=>det(A)=0=>A^2=Tr(A).A=>A^n=[Tr(A)]^{n-1}.A=>[Tr(A)]^{n-1}.A=O_2.$

I. $Tr(A)=0=>A^2=Tr(A).A=O_2;$

II. $A=O_2=>A^2=O_2.$

Comment: The matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ has vanishing trace but does not square to zero.

Comment: Case I uses again the partial result that det(A)=0.

Comment: Rasmus, please carefully read the statement of the problem in question.
Your example does not satisfy the condition of enunciation:$A^n=O_2$

Comment: $Det(A)=-1\neq 0$, thus, i.e. the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ does not satisfy the condition